# Matlab: creating vector from 2 input vectors

Tags: matlab

What I would like to do in Matlab is to create a vector `C` with values from a predefined vector `A`, while the size is determined by `B`.

F.i.: with `A = [2;1;3]` and `B = [3;2;1]`, matlab should generate somehow the vector `C = [2;2;2;1;1;3]` (so 3 times 2 because B(1) = 3 and A(1) = 2, ...).

I wonder if there is an easy way to do this. I was trying something with repmat and kron commands in Matlab, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Check the duplicate question. Lots of good answers there

Comment: Thank you! It is funny that he also mentions that he has tried repmat and kron, haha :)